# DotNetNuke/Evoq - add custom stylesheets just before closing head

Tags: css, asp.net, dotnetnuke, head

I'm trying to add two custom css stylesheets just before the closing `</head>` without breaking skin and/or hacking skin?

I built two css files to turn site into responsive design without actually touching any of the skin/template code so it's necessary to have in last ordering of css files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best best is to register it using the DNN CSS Include skin object, adding it to your skin and simply setting a priority that is high.

```
<dnn:DnnCssInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/Your-PathHere" Priority="100" />
```

You just need to be sure that you have the following register in your skin as well.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" Namespace="DotNetNuke.Web.Client.ClientResourceManagement" Assembly="DotNetNuke.Web.Client" %>
```

The full [API Details for Client Resource Management](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/client-resource-management-api) will help.  Highest DNN priority appears to be 35